# Modal pop up AJAX extension for button save

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, modalpopup

I have a button that makes saving a record in the database, but want the user to press the button to be notified that the registration was successful in another case to be informed that such registration exists. As can be done with modal popup extensions (AJAX)
This functionality be done in asp.net C #

Here's the code for the server-side

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!DALAtribut.CheckId("SELECT * FROM AtributPhone WHERE ID_Employee = '" + DDLEmployeeCreate.SelectedItem.Value.ToString() + "'"))
            {
                AtributPhone atribut = new AtributPhone()
                {
                    ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    ID_Category = Guid.Parse(DDLSubCategoryCreate.SelectedItem.Value),
                    ID_Employee = Guid.Parse(DDLEmployeeCreate.SelectedItem.Value),
                    ID_Institution = Guid.Parse(DDLInstitutionCreate.SelectedItem.Value),
                    ID_Office = Guid.Parse(DDLOfficeCreate.SelectedItem.Value),
                    ID_Phone = Guid.Parse(DDLPhoneCreate.SelectedItem.Value)
                };

                bd.AtributPhones.AddObject(atribut);
                bd.SaveChanges();
                isValid = false;
                //btnAdd.OnClientClick = "return confirm('Registration was successfully added!');";
            }
            gvAtribut.DataBind();
        }
```

and here

```
<%@ Page Title="Atribute" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Administrator/SiteAdmin.Master"
    AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AtributsPhone.aspx.cs" Inherits="ContactData.Administrator.AtributsPhone" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowMyModalPopupSuccess() {
            var modal = $find('mpeSuccess');
            modal.show();
        }
        function HideModalPopupSuccess() {
            var modal = $find('mpeSuccess');
            modal.hide();
        }
        function fnClickSuccess(sender, e) {
            __doPostBack(sender, e);
        }
    </script>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="smAtribut" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upAtribut" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tableCSS" style="width: 180px;" align="right">
                        Institution :
                    </td>
                    <td class="tableCSS">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLInstitutionCreate" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Width="250px"
                            OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDLInstitutionCreate_SelectedIndexChanged" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tableCSS" style="width: 180px;" align="right">
                        Phone :
                    </td>
                    <td class="tableCSS">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLPhoneCreate" runat="server" Width="250px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDLPhoneCreate_SelectedIndexChanged"
                            AutoPostBack="True" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tableCSS" style="width: 180px;" align="right">
                        Section :
                    </td>
                    <td class="tableCSS">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLSubCategoryCreate" runat="server" Width="250px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDLSubCategoryCreate_SelectedIndexChanged"
                            AutoPostBack="True" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tableCSS" style="width: 180px;" align="right">
                        Employee :
                    </td>
                    <td class="tableCSS">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLEmployeeCreate" runat="server" Width="250px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDLEmployeeCreate_SelectedIndexChanged"
                            AutoPostBack="True" OnInit="DDLEmployeeCreate_Init" OnTextChanged="DDLEmployeeCreate_TextChanged" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tableCSS" style="width: 180px;" align="right">
                        Office :
                    </td>
                    <td class="tableCSS">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLOfficeCreate" runat="server" Width="250px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDLOfficeCreate_SelectedIndexChanged"
                            AutoPostBack="True" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tableCSS" style="width: 180px;" align="right">
                    </td>
                    <td class="tableCSS" align="right">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
<asp:Panel ID="pSuccesMessage" runat="server" style="background-color:Gray; display:none;">
            <p style="padding:20px;text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;color:Black;">
            Registration was successfully added!
            </p>
            <div style="padding: 10px; vertical-align: middle" align="center">
            <asp:Button ID="btnOK" runat="server" Text="Ok"/>
            </div>     
            </asp:Panel>
            <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeSuccess" runat="server"
                PopupControlID="pSuccesMessage"
                TargetControlID="btnAdd" 
                BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" 
                OkControlID="btnOK"
                OnOkScript="HideModalPopupSuccess()">
            </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
            <asp:GridView ID="gvAtribut" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
                CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="sdsAtribute" ForeColor="#333333"
                GridLines="None" DataMember="DefaultView" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ButtonType="Image" DeleteImageUrl="~/Styles/delete-img.png" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" ReadOnly="True" Visible="False" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="EmployeeName" HeaderText="Name" ReadOnly="True"
                        SortExpression="[Employee].[EmployeeName]" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="[Employee].[Email]" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone" SortExpression="[PhoneCard].[Phone]" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="InternPhone" HeaderText="int. Phone" SortExpression="[PhoneCard].[InternPhone]" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="WorkerMobile" HeaderText="Mobile" SortExpression="[Employee].[WorkerMobile]" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="NrOffice" HeaderText="Office" SortExpression="[Office].[NrOffice]" />
                </Columns>
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" Height="50px" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsAtribute" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ContactDataConnectionString %>"
                SelectCommand="SELECT [AtributPhone].[ID],[Employee].[EmployeeName], [Employee].[Email], [PhoneCard].[Phone], [PhoneCard].[InternPhone], [Employee].[WorkerMobile], [Office].[NrOffice] FROM [AtributPhone], [Employee], [PhoneCard], [Office] WHERE [AtributPhone].[ID_Phone] = [PhoneCard].[ID] AND [AtributPhone].[ID_Employee] = [Employee].[ID] AND [AtributPhone].[ID_Office] = [Office].[ID] ORDER BY [Employee].[EmployeeName] ASC"
                DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM AtributPhone WHERE (ID = @ID)"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DDLInstitutionCreate" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DDLPhoneCreate" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DDLSubCategoryCreate" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DDLEmployeeCreate" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DDLOfficeCreate" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAdd" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: What is the question ? What have you tried so far ?

Comment: What is the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: client-side event is not transmitted on the server and processed on

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a question here, but this should help you get started.

Try this: http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/03/how-to-show-modalpopup-to-edit-gridview.html

Comment: No problem, if that helps you out, please check that it was the answer.